# PHP - list number with url

Tags: php, numbers

example php like this:

```
  for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){
    $url = "http://example.org/12".$i."<br />";
    echo $url;
  }
```

i want output :

```
http://example.org/1201
http://example.org/1202
http://example.org/1203
http://example.org/1204
http://example.org/1205
http://example.org/1206
http://example.org/1207
http://example.org/1208
http://example.org/1209
http://example.org/1210
http://example.org/1211
http://example.org/1212
.......
http://example.org/1220
```

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Comment: So what's your question? I see code that does what you're asking for.

Comment: ori output is `http://example.org/121` not `http://example.org/1201`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str_pad()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){
    $i = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $url = "http://example.org/12".$i."<br />";
    echo $url;
}
```

You can also use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++){
    $i = sprintf("%02d",$i);
    $url = "http://example.org/12".$i."<br />";
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: that's the most beautiful thing i've ever seen; thanks for sharing it!